# EC P 256 x,y coardinates into public key?

Tags: cryptography, public-key, elliptic-curve

I have JWT(is actually JWK) which cintains a header of

```
"publicKeySet": {
"keys": [
  {
    "kid": "0",
    "kty": "EC",
    "crv": "P-256",
    "x": "TVRb9i0TUz2JVgfejnYSi-ux8hCjYu2IIvis9ov_i20",
    "y": "ot6nTre05Li6-RW5v36TXnI32-ZUuwTQx5baMXOs5do",
    "x5c": [
      "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",
      "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"
    ]
  },
```

I need a public key, but i dont know whether this information is helpful to get EC public key? i need a public key something like this..

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----NFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAECpqQ7EJ3Ba86QIQiA0nn0PPDp2sjJAGXoJt487h1yZOb8UTBC4NqFrFf5Y8zMk1YcyWB0l9jUSNaDLtMwibjJw==-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Is it possible? and is there any other way to get public key? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JWT posted above is acutally JWK.

There is a great tool online to get the .pem out of JWK

```
https://8gwifi.org/jwkconvertfunctions.jsp
```

and in order to get the .pem out of JWK using python, we can use the jwcrypto lib

```
from jwcrypto import jwk
import json
jskey=json.loads('put your jwk here')
key = jwk.JWK(**expkey)
res=key.export_to_pem()
print(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have everything you need.

In elliptic curve cryptography (with curve P-256), a public key is simply an `X,Y` co-ordinate on the cartesian plane and finite field over which the curve is defined.

Thus your public key is:

```
"x": "TVRb9i0TUz2JVgfejnYSi-ux8hCjYu2IIvis9ov_i20"

"y": "ot6nTre05Li6-RW5v36TXnI32-ZUuwTQx5baMXOs5do"
```

These `X,Y` values are encoded with `base64`, however be aware that `_` should be replaced with `/`, and `-` with `+` (this is because URL safe base64 was used).

Comment: Do i need to concatinate the both x and y? i  am using python..

Comment: and what is x5c for? its of no use to create a public key?

Comment: @HassanHaroon it depends on the format of the public key, ASN1, etc, - how it's structured is dependant on the lib you're using. x5c, is an X.509 cert chain.

Comment: can you suggest me a lib for python?

Comment: sure, what are you trying to do? Whats the goal? encrypt or sign or ?

Comment: Actuall i am using a  ATECC608A chip from microchip. It generates public key and private key securely wihin the chip. In theory user can generate the public key from the chip but it also provides a manifest for  hundreds of the chips so that user dont have to run the script on each device for the public keys. In that manifest it has a JWT as defined in my question so i need to generate the public key out of it so that i can store that on the cloud and then sign my messages with the private key with in the devicee..

Comment: So this public which i need is being use as authentication on the cloud